# Use Facebook share meta tags outside of head?

Tags: facebook, share, meta-tags

Our websites article backend does not allow access to anything above `</head>` which prevents our writers from specifying shareable content with use of the facebook meta tags. Anyone know an alternative route of specifying the article image, title, and description of a shared article without accessing the `<head>`?  My search yielded no results, my apologies if this has been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you give your writers a way to create meta tags in other separate pages, outside of your article backend?

The Facebook Open Graph meta tag content does not need to reside within the same page that the like button is rendered on.  The shareable content (images/titles/descriptions) will be pulled from the meta content of the page referenced in the URL parameter of the Facebook button.  So you could create separate pages corresponding to each of your articles that serve simply to supply the meta content for the Facebook news story post.  The Facebook news story posts would still link back to your articles as long as the meta "og:url" in the placeholder file is set to your article url.